# How to returning different data types from a function depending upon the arguments passed

Tags: rust

#### Introduction

In my rust library, I have "Shape" objects (called Types in rust). Each shape object has attributes.
Some of those attributes like "color", "name" etc are string values, some of these attributes are integers, and some bool.
The way attributes module is implemented is such that for each attribute there is a different `getter` and `setter` function.

An example

```rust
pub struct Attributes{
    //--strings
    bounding_rectangle_color:String,
    shadow_color:String,
    name:String,
    color:String,
   ...
pub fn set_bounding_rectangle_color(&mut self,v:String){
        self.bounding_rectangle_color = v;
    }
    pub fn get_bounding_rectangle_color(&self)->String{
        String::from(&self.bounding_rectangle_color)
    }
```

This is (in my humble opinion) the correct way of doing it since each attribute has its own get and set function these functions will soon have some logic specific to that attribute.

**The Challange**
Though having separate getters and setters for each attribute is great however the same API can not be exposed to the user being confusing.
the user should have something like

```rust
let some_result:???? = my_shape.get_attr(attribute_name);
```

The problem is that the get_attr function has to return either a bool or string or int etc (but it can not return 2 different types).
*Please keep in mind the problem is getting get_attr and not set_attr since in set_attr we can just take in a string and change it internally to whatever.*

I want to wrap the attributes module in a wrapper such that internally attributes can use separate getter and setter for each value whereas from the top the wrapper should be able to communicate with attribute module using a simple API like

```rust
let value = shape.get_attr(attribute_name);
```

#### What I have tried so far

**Tuple Structs**
I tried to use a tuple struct in place of each attribute inside this tuple there will be the data type of this attribute (ie either bool, string, etc).

> BUT the problem was the same that at some point that tuple had to return a value and that value type can not be unknown at compile time

### Returning Functions

Once again when we return a function we have to tell the return type of that function as well.

#### Summary

Rust does not have union types, am I just trying to re-implement union types??? am I going in the wrong direction .. please help

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have a single accessor for multiple attributes, as it can be confusing to both the developers and the compiler. If you, however, really want to do it this way, you'd probably have to return the value in an enum.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with FZs here. Unless you have a singular attribute type, which *could be an `enum`*, you're making a mess of things here. I'm not sure how it's "confusing" having multiple getters, as that's how the vast majority of code works. I can only think of a few exceptions like [`fcntl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) but these are *really* old and are a product of how limited C is.

Comment: Thanks a lot tadman.. can you please explain a bit. I tried with enums as well. So if a function like get_attr( ) takes in an enum as the attribute but still the return type is not known at compile time.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to return multiple types is to return an enum. For example, you could define an enum as follows (with the exact types/names up to you):

```rust
enum Return {
    Int(usize),
    String(String),
    Bool(bool),
}
```

From here, you could have a function like so:

```rust
fn do_something(num: usize) -> Return {
    match num {
        1 => Return::Int(1),
        2 => Return::String(String::from("two")),
        3 => Return::Bool(true),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

Now, depending on the input parameter, it will return different types. To actually do something with the types, you could do something like:

```rs
if let Return::Int(int) = do_something(1) {
    // do something with the int
}
```

However, it might be best to try and find another way to solve your problem - having a single getter/setter is not really better than having individual getters/setters, and could lead to your code being confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. After some more reading I also reached the conclusion that using one bottle-neck function for accessing all the attributes is not a good solution. Also sending multiple values using enum (as you mentioned) is the best way of doing this. Thanks again